# Surface integral domain to surface function...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

In a surface integral where the domain of the surface is its projection on a plane, how can there be a function from the projection to the surface if the area of the surface is greater than its projection? I understand that we compute |ru x rv| to scale the area, but the surface is still the image of its domain. How is this possible if the number of "points" increases because the area of the surface increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface is the image of the domain, but we have a continuum of points in our domain, allowing us to increase the area of the "image".

For instance $f(x)=2x$, here $f:[0,1]\to[0,2]$, this is due to having an continuum domain.

If we do not have a continuum, other situations occur, i.e. consider the same mapping $f(x)=2x$, but now consider the domain $\mathbb{N}$, here:

$f:\mathbb{N}\to 2\mathbb{N}$, where $2\mathbb{N}$ is the set of positive even integers which has "less points" than $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: So it's because the reals are continuous?

Comment: its because they are "everywhere", this is what I mean by continuum

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)